# How to include matching values when using sort_values + head()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, group-by

I have a `df`:

```
       Date Symbol Person
0   2019 Q3      A    Bob
1   2019 Q3      A    Jon
2   2019 Q3      B    Rob
3   2019 Q3      B    Ron
4   2019 Q3      C    Jay
5   2019 Q3      C    Ray
6   2019 Q3      D    Fay
7   2019 Q2      A    Bob
8   2019 Q2      A    Jon
9   2019 Q2      B    Rob
10  2019 Q2      B    Ron
11  2019 Q2      C    Jay
12  2019 Q2      C    Ray
13  2019 Q2      D    Fay
14  2019 Q2      D    Bre
15  2019 Q2      E    Jon
16  2019 Q2      F    Ron
```

Where I am trying to find the top two `Symbols` per quarter by count. But as you can see, sometimes there are more than two `Symbols` with the same count value for a given `Date` (e.g., symbols `A`, `B`, *and* `C` in `2019 Q3`, and symbols `A`, `B`, `C` *and* `D` in `2019 Q2`.

When I do:

```
df['Count'] = df.groupby(['Date', 'Symbol'])['Person'].transform('nunique')
df = df[['Date', 'Symbol', 'Count']]
df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep="first", inplace=True)
df = df.sort_values('Count', ascending=False).groupby('Date').head(2).sort_index()
```

My output only includes the first two:

```
   Date Symbol  Count
2019 Q3      A      2
2019 Q3      B      2
2019 Q2      A      2
2019 Q2      B      2
```

But how can I get it so that *all* the tied `counts` instances are included too, so that it looks like:

```
   Date Symbol  Count
2019 Q3      A      2
2019 Q3      B      2
2019 Q3      C      2
2019 Q2      A      2
2019 Q2      B      2
2019 Q2      C      2
2019 Q2      D      2
```

Comment: are you able to show a sample of your expected output?

Comment: Sure, just updated

Comment: I know. Just haven't tested the answer yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for q in df.Date.unique():
        f = df.loc[df.Date == q]
        f = f.groupby(['Date', 'Symbol']).size().nlargest(n,keep='all').to_frame().reset_index()
        f.columns = ['Date', 'Symbol', 'Count']
        new_df = pd.concat([new_df, f])
```

Answer (score 1):

We can `GroupBy` and get the `nunique`s (whithout `transforming`), and filter where `Count` is greater or equal to the second value in the `Count` column:

```
df.sort_values(['Date', 'Symbol'], inplace=True)
g = df.groupby(['Date', 'Symbol']).Person.nunique().rename('Count')
g[g >= g.groupby(level=0).transform('nth', 1)].reset_index()

    Date    Symbol  Count
0  2019Q2      A      2
1  2019Q2      B      2
2  2019Q2      C      2
3  2019Q2      D      2
4  2019Q3      A      2
5  2019Q3      B      2
6  2019Q3      C      2
```

This works because since the data is sorted, selecting all values greater or equal to the second value in the `Count` column will ensure that we will allways include either:

- The two highest counts (in the case the second is different)
- All counts which are equal to the first in the case the second is the same as the first

Comment: very smart, nice one. Didn't account that the variables may be different.

Comment: I'm not getting the same output. For example, for 2019 Q2, it's also returning `Symbols` where `Count` is `1` (like `E` and `F`), and for 2019 Q3, it returns `D`. Also, how do I specify n# of counts (i.e., say I want the top 5 instead of the top 2).